# Save images from WhatsApp using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am currently working on developing a WhatsApp bot using Selenium, which will open WhatsApp in a web browser. The goal of the bot is to identify conversations that contain unread messages. Specifically, I would like the bot to determine if one of the last two unread messages in a conversation is an image. If an image is found, the bot should enter the respective conversation, download the image to a designated "images" folder, and send the same image back to the sender.

```
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
# from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

# Define the folder path to save the images
image_folder = 'images'
os.makedirs(image_folder, exist_ok=True)

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=chrome-data")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com')  # Already authenticated

time.sleep(15)
conversations = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="pane-side"]/div[1]/div/div/div')
count = []

for index, conversation in enumerate(conversations):
    try:
        unread_indicator = conversation.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                                     '.l7jjieqr.il1gyv3w.ei5e7seu.h0viaqh7.tpmajp1w.k07a8sro.riy2oczp'
                                                     '.dsh4tgtl.hnx8ox4h.gz7w46tb.lyutrhe2.qfejxiq4.fewfhwl7.ovhn1urg'
                                                     '.ap18qm3b.ikwl5qvt.j90th5db.aumms1qt')

    except:
        continue

    if unread_indicator.is_displayed():
        count.append(index)
        print(f"Conversation {index}: {conversation.text}")
```

However, I have encountered a challenge in implementing the functionality to filter and open only those conversations where the last two messages include an image.